# Is Z3 python interface threadsafe?

Tags: multithreading, z3py

within the python interface of Z3 variables can be created via methods: *Int, Real, ...*.

Does anybody know whether these methods can be called concurrently in python? That means, are those methods threadsafe?

I would like to create variables concurrently.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so based on the documentation [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3.html#Context).

> It is not safe to access Z3 objects from multiple threads. The only
>   exception is the method `interrupt()` that can be used to interrupt()
>   a long computation.